# Remove all hidden files except specific files

Tags: linux, wordpress, shell

I have a vps server that had been attacked with a virus which keeps injecting many hidden files. How can I delete all hidden files in directories and sub directories of the `public_html` folder, except two files: `.htaccess` and `.user.ini`?

I have tried the below Linux command, but without success:

```
find "public_html" -type f -name '.*' -delete !(".htaccess"|".user.ini")
```

Comment: That's doesn't seem like a good idea, to just delete the files that the virus is creating....

Comment: I guess I have already killed the virus , I have installed wordfence and I have added many security precaution , the virus was not able anymore to stop my website , it did it many time before ; I need now just deleting the restes of this virus

Comment: Why not just delete everything on the server and reupload the important files?

Comment: I have many website hosted on this vps server I can't start from the scratch

Comment: How about: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+malware

Comment: good idea rene thanks

Comment: You're fighting an uphill battle ... like taking aspirin against COVID.  Take the machine off-line, make a full-disk clone for forensics; find out how the malware got there, restore from the last good known back-up and patch the access vector.

Comment: hhhh your exemple killed me , I know I have stopped the virus he can't injected any additional file , but I need to delete its restes

Comment: @KGIII this question isn't even on topic on [wordpress.se]. A different question, one that asks about backing up a wordpress site might be, but that is not what _this_ question is asking.

Comment: D'oh! You're right. I forgot that they're not allowed to ask things like configuring plugins there. The rest still applied, but it was too late to edit it. @terdon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people have already told you in the comments, this is a very bad idea. You will never be sure you've cleaned everything up and standard procedure for something like this is to wipe the sever and restore from a clean backup.

That said, the reason your `find` command isn't working is because `find` doesn't understand extended globbing patterns like `!(".htaccess"|".user.ini")`. Instead, you need to use `find`'s own syntax:

```
find . -type f -name '.*' ! -name .htaccess -a ! -name .user.ini -delete
```

Or

```
find . -type f -name '.*' ! \( -name .htaccess -o -name .user.ini \) -delete
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon , you answer me question